# Calling QOpenGLWidget::update() several times normally results in just one QOpenGLWidget::paintGL() call

Tags: qt

I have implemented a widget, that extends to QOpenGLWidget to display YUV framebuffers & these frame buffers are coming from hardware camera. Implemented YUV to RGB conversion logic inside overridden paintGL() function.

When ever I received a frame from hardware, I will call update() function on QOpenGLWidget & paintGL() function will be invoked by QT. I am getting YUV framebuffers at 60 FPS rate from hardware, So I am calling 60 update() functions in a second. But observed that paintGL() functions aren't called 60 times in a seconds.

I have following two issues:

- Update() function does not cause an immediate paintGL()
- update() several times normally results in just one QOpenGLWidget::paintGL()

Because of these two reasons some frames are missing to display.

I need a function to immediate calling of paintGL() function. How to resolve these issues or is there any other better solution?

Comment: The behaviour you're seeing with `update()` is exactly as expected and documented.  Have you tried calling [`QWidget::repaint()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#repaint-1) instead?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it & observed same as update()

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].